# Lucene indexer goes OutOfMemory on a tiny document collection

Tags: java, lucene, indexing, search-engine, out-of-memory

I'm trying to make an index of several text documents.

Their content is just field tab-separated strings:

```
WORD<\t>w1<\t>w2<\t>...<\t>wn

POS<\t>pos1<\t>pos2_a:pos2_b:pos2_c<\t>...<\t>posn_a:posn_b
...
```

For the POS field, '`:'-`separated tokens correspond to the same ambiguous word.

There are 5 documents with the total size of 10 MB.
While indexing, java uses about 2 GB of RAM and finally throws an OOM error.

```
String join_token = tok.nextToken();
// atomic tokens correspond to separate parses
String[] atomic_tokens = StringUtils.split(join_token, ':');
// marking each token with the parse number
for (int token_index = 0; token_index < atomic_tokens.length; ++token_index) {
  atomic_tokens[token_index] += String.format("|%d", token_index);
}
String join_token_with_payloads = StringUtils.join(atomic_tokens, " ");
TokenStream stream = new WhitespaceTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_41, // OOM exception appears here
                                             new StringReader(join_token_with_payloads));
// all these parses belong to the same position in the document
stream = new PositionFilter(stream, 0);
stream = new DelimitedPayloadTokenFilter(stream, '|', new IntegerEncoder());
stream.addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);
stream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
feature = new Field(name,
                    join_token,
                    attributeFieldType);
feature.setTokenStream(stream);
inDocument.add(feature);
```

What is wrong with this code from the memory point of view, And how to do indexing with as little data as possible held in RAM?

Answer (score 1):

If i understood the problem right (i didn't tried it out) this are my suggestions

1. It's good practice to use Camel case in the code which is a convention for java
2. You don't need to generate the positions manually just create a field with Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS and the metrics will end up in the index.
3. The creation of such huge arrays of String causes an really big memory overhead -> use StringBuilder.
4. Use LetterTokenizer to tokenize the stream or write your own tokenizer by extending CharTokenizer
5. Btw great book [Lucene in Action](http://www.manning.com/hatcher3/)

Comment: 2. I use PositionFilter because I need all part-of-speech tags belonging to one word to go to the same position in the index.
3. You mean that having a huge String is better on memory than a huge String[] array?
Overall I can't get why there's so much RAM used. I tried to do forced garbage collection but it made no difference.
Seems like faulty resource release somewhere inside Lucene.

Comment: You can always create a custom Attribute which you can add trough a TokenFilter. Personaly i done that with Sentence detection matrics, named entity metrics and serialized it into the PayloadAttribute before Lucene 4. Now you can create you custom codec and write your index how you want.

Comment: Regarding the String[] size here is the explanation: 64-bit JVM, for a String you have 16 byte for the object overhead(Class, flags, lock), need space for an int field (for the character count) and space for a reference to the underlying char array and int which represents the hash, plus padding 4byte. The char arary in turn requires 20 bytes overhead (16 object and 4 for length of the array). This comes to 40 byte + 16 bytes (for an empty char array) + size of array(in char(2 byte)) + padding. Only for one string

Comment: If you create a StringBuilder you only have the object overhead (16 byte), int for the size (4 byte), int for the hash (4byte) and reference to char array(8 byte) which is 40 byte. Char array is 20 byte + size of array(in char(2 byte)) + padding

Comment: I wrapped my TokenStream above in a custom Analyzer and passed it to the IndexWriterConfig. This has fixed the leak. I still don't understand how it actually helped.